# How to work around this Safari float rendering bug

Tags: html, css

I need to display text around a floated element that itself has been pushed downwards. The HTML/CSS is very simple:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="shim"></div>
    <div id="myimg"></div> 
    <p>This is a test to demonstrate the float overwriting issue. The blue box represent an image that I don't wish the text to overwrite...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
}

#shim {
    float:right;
    width: 1px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}

#myimg {
    clear:both;
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, however in Safari the text overwrites my floated element.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the bug (obviously, you'll need safari to see it):

http://jsfiddle.net/8JLFp/

Can anyone find a solution or suggest another way of doing this?

Comment: It looks fine in Safari 5.1.7

Comment: Safari 6.0.2 don't work as expected with chrome.

Comment: It'm using Safari 6.0.2. It doesn't work with that version.

Comment: 4.5 years and this bug is still not fixed in Safari! I ran into this today, open my demo page in Safari: https://codepen.io/smohadjer/pen/RLBKGb

Answer (score 0):

[Please check the same issue on this site. May be this helps you.](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/safari_bug_floa)

Possible Solutions.

1. Try adding clear:both divs
2. Use overflow:hidden

Comment: div { overflow:hidden}  ... Add this in css.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the mentioned link which JANENE said on September 11, 2008.

Comment: Just tried on the fiddle. It has the curious effect of pushing the text down, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be an old question, but its still valid today.

I got mine fixed by adding to the parent tag :

```css
style="width: 100%;"
```

Which in your case, the `div` with `id=container`.

Hope this helps.